# For how long are state and federal aircraft registrations valid?

Tags: usa, aircraft-registration

How long is a state registration valid for and how long is a federal registration valid for?
and for state I mean North Dakota if any of you know where to look for that.

Comment: State registration depends on the state. In Wisconsin, it is required to be renewed annually. Some states do not require registration.

Comment: California doesn’t have a registration system per se, but we pay property tax on the aircraft each year, so if you own an aircraft you are "registered" with the state.

Comment: Cheers thanks guys !

Answer (score 3):

Federal registration is for three years, [according to the FAA](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/reregistration/) (the actual regulations are in [14 CFR 47.40](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=dd4fc88c39d8c70c51c0f9dfeb36ed3f&mc=true&node=se14.1.47_140&rgn=div8)):

> - Aircraft registration issued due to renewal expires three years from the expiration date of the previous certificate.
> - Aircraft registration issued to a new, import, or reinstated aircraft entering or re-entering the U.S. Civil Aircraft Register
>     expires three years after the last day of the month in which it is
>     issued.

State registration - if any - is up to each state so you need to check with the state where the aircraft's owner registered it.

Comment: Cheers thanks for that